# Content in tab does not show in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have added a custom tab on my module’s details page, however, the tab is rendered but the content for the tab isn’t showing. There isn’t any error in the console log as well.
[image]

> index.js

```
import './page/wt-shopfinder-list';
import './page/wt-shopfinder-detail';

import './view/wt-shopfinder-detail-base';
import './view/wt-shopfinder-detail-review';

const { Module } = Shopware;

Module.register('example-shopfinder', {
type: 'plugin',
name: 'ExampleShopFinder',
title: 'example-shopfinder.general.mainMenuItemGeneral',
description: 'example-shopfinder.general.descriptionTextModule',
version: '1.0.0',
targetVersion: '1.0.0',
color: '#9AA8B5',
icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag',
entity:'wt_shop_finder',
routes: {
    index: {
        components: {
            default: "wt-shopfinder-list"
        },
        path: 'index',
        
    },
    detail: {
        component: 'wt-shopfinder-detail',
        path: 'detail/:id',
        redirect: {
            name: 'example.shopfinder.detail.base',
        },
        children: {
            base: {
                component: 'wt-shopfinder-detail-base',
                path: 'base',
                meta: {
                    parentPath: 'example.shopfinder.index'
                },
            },
            review: {
                component: 'wt-shopfinder-detail-review',
                path: 'review',
                meta: {
                    parentPath: 'example.shopfinder.index'
                },
            },
        },
        meta: {
            appSystem: {
                view: 'detail',
            },
        },
        props: {
            default(route) {
                return {
                    shopFinderId: route.params.id,
                };
            },
        },
    }
},

navigation: [{
    id: 'wt-shopfinder',
    label: 'example-shopfinder.menu.mainMenuItemGeneral',
    color: '#ff3d58',
    icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag-product',
    path: 'example.shopfinder.index',
    parent: "sw-marketing",
    position: 100,
}],
});
```

> wt-shopfinder-detail/wt-shopfinder-detail-html.twig

```
<sw-tabs
            class="wt_shopfinder-detail-page__tabs"
            position-identifier="wt-shopfinder-detail"
        >
            {% block wt_shopfinder_detail_content_tabs_general %}
            <sw-tabs-item
                :route="generalRoute"
                :title="$tc('sw-customer.detail.tabGeneral')"
                :disabled="false"
            >
                {{ $tc('sw-promotion-v2.detail.tabs.tabGeneral') }}
            </sw-tabs-item>
            {% endblock %}
            {% block wt_shopfinder_detail_content_tabs_general2 %}
            <sw-tabs-item
                :route="reviewRoute"
                :title="$tc('sw-customer.detail.tabGeneral')"
                :disabled="false"
            >
                Review
            </sw-tabs-item>
            {% endblock %}
        </sw-tabs>
```

> wt-shopfinder-detail/index.js

```
//Sharing only the url part for tab navigation
generalRoute() {
        console.log("ID = "+this.shopFinderId);
        return {
            name: 'webbytroops.shopfinder.detail.base',
            params: { id: this.shopFinderId },
        };
    },
```

> wt-shopfinder-detail-base/index.js

```
import template from './wt-shopfinder-detail-base.html.twig';

const { Component } = Shopware;
const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;

Component.register('wt-shopfinder-detail-base', {
    template,
    
    inject: ['repositoryFactory'],
    
    metaInfo() {
        return {
            title: "Custom"
        };
    }    
});
```

> wt-shopfinder-detail-base/wt-shopfinder-detail-base.html.twig

```
<sw-card title="Custom">
    Hello world!
</sw-card>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct pattern for the route would be `{moduleName}.{routeName}.{childName}` and in the module name dashes are replaced by dots. So the correct route in your case should be `example.shopfinder.detail.base`.

Also, unless you omitted it, you're missing the `router-view` tag after the `sw-tabs` component.

```html
<sw-container>
    <sw-tabs>
        ...
    </sw-tabs>

    <router-view />
</sw-container>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing <router-view />. I am exploring it with reference of the Core module but I didn't notice this specific thing. Do you know if there is any guide apart from the official document of Shopware?
Thanks for the help!